# I want to calculate the difference between two values in a "distance_table = []" with permutations, how can I use permutations correctly in this case?

Tags: python, algorithm, csv, combinations, permutation

I want to calculate the difference between two values in a distancetable which is read in from a file, a csv file with a number of cities with distances between them. In the .csv-file I have the first row with cities, 
    like this:

> Barcelona;Belgrade;Berlin

The next rows are the distances between the cities, written like this:

> 0;1528.13;1497.61
>
> 1528.13;0;999.25
>
> 1497.61;999.25;0

For example, the distance from Barcelona to Barcelona is 0, (first number), Barcelona and Belgrade is 1528.13, (second), Belgrade and Berlin 999.25.. etc

I am trying to create an algorithm to search for the shortest path through all the cities in file like this. But I will need to use Python and probably permutations from itertools.

I don't know how I can use permutations correctly so I can add together the distance from the different possibilites. How can I do this?

So I am importing permutations, csv, reading in the file, and and starting from here...

```
from itertools import permutations
import csv

# Read data file
distance_table = []
with open('european_cities.csv') as file:
  reader = csv.reader(file,delimiter=';')
  # First row is the city names
  city_names = reader.next()
  # The rest of the rows are the distance table
  for row in reader:
    distance_table.append([float(cell) for cell in row])
```

so now I can fore example see from the distance_table the distance between city A and city B like this:

> distance_table[city_A][city_B]

How can I loop through all combinations in the permutation when I only want each city to appear once??

I want for example: cityA-cityB + cityB-cityC + cityC-cityA 
and not: cityA-cityB + cityA-cityC + cityB-cityC + cityC-cityA etcetra . . .

I would like to use different algorithms here, firstly a stupid algorithm lie brute force to see the difference in time between this and a smarter algorithm, like the shortest-path algorithm.

But I don't know how I can loop through the cities. How?

Comment: I'd not use permutations (brute forcing). I'd construct a *graph* of the cities and their distances between them and use a shortest-path algorithm.

Comment: I am thinking about using a few different algorithms, just so see the different time efficiency between them, so for example I would like to use a stupid algorithm, like brute force, and a few smarter ones, like the shortest-path algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want all permutations without any city to appearing twice, yet your example has the starting city (cityA) listed again at the end:

> I want for example: cityA-cityB + cityB-cityC + cityC-cityA

So, assuming the first city appearing again at the end is actually what you meant, I think the following shows how you could generate the permutations of cities you want — if that assumption is wrong, simply remove the one line where the first city is duplicated.

In order to get differing total distances (with three it's always the same), I added a fourth city and changed the output format so it's more compact to better accommodate more cities.

```
Barcelona;Belgrade;Berlin;Brussels
0;1528.13;1497.61;1346.0
1528.13;0;999.25;1723.0
1497.61;999.25;0;764.0
1346.0;1723.0;764.0;0
```

Here's the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import csv
import functools
try:
    from itertools import izip, imap
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    izip = zip
    imap = map
from itertools import permutations, repeat

# Create a distance dictionary from csv data file with entries like this:
#     (city_a, city_b): float(distance-between-city_a-and-city_b)
# for all pairs of city names in the file.
data_filename = 'european_cities.csv'
dist_dict = {}
with open(data_filename, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    cities = next(reader)  # header row
    num_cities = len(cities)
    for city in cities:  # should be a row of distances for each city
        from_city_iter = repeat(city, num_cities)
        dist_dict.update((pair for pair in izip(izip(from_city_iter, cities),
                                                imap(float, next(reader)))
                            if pair[1])) # skip 0 distances (city_a == city_b)

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2,s3), ..."
    a, b = iter(iterable), iter(iterable)
    next(b)  # advance second iterator one iteration
    return izip(a, b)

for tour in permutations(cities, len(cities)):
    tour += (tour[0],)  # make round trip by appending starting city
    route = '->'.join(tour)
    dist = sum(dist_dict[city_a, city_b] for city_a, city_b in pairwise(tour))
    print('{:^49}: {:,}'.format(route, dist))
```

Output:

```
Barcelona->Belgrade->Berlin->Brussels->Barcelona : 4,637.38
Barcelona->Belgrade->Brussels->Berlin->Barcelona : 5,512.74
Barcelona->Berlin->Belgrade->Brussels->Barcelona : 5,565.86
Barcelona->Berlin->Brussels->Belgrade->Barcelona : 5,512.74
Barcelona->Brussels->Belgrade->Berlin->Barcelona : 5,565.86
Barcelona->Brussels->Berlin->Belgrade->Barcelona : 4,637.38
 Belgrade->Barcelona->Berlin->Brussels->Belgrade : 5,512.74
 Belgrade->Barcelona->Brussels->Berlin->Belgrade : 4,637.38
 Belgrade->Berlin->Barcelona->Brussels->Belgrade : 5,565.86
 Belgrade->Berlin->Brussels->Barcelona->Belgrade : 4,637.38
 Belgrade->Brussels->Barcelona->Berlin->Belgrade : 5,565.86
 Belgrade->Brussels->Berlin->Barcelona->Belgrade : 5,512.74
  Berlin->Barcelona->Belgrade->Brussels->Berlin  : 5,512.74
  Berlin->Barcelona->Brussels->Belgrade->Berlin  : 5,565.86
  Berlin->Belgrade->Barcelona->Brussels->Berlin  : 4,637.38
  Berlin->Belgrade->Brussels->Barcelona->Berlin  : 5,565.86
  Berlin->Brussels->Barcelona->Belgrade->Berlin  : 4,637.38
  Berlin->Brussels->Belgrade->Barcelona->Berlin  : 5,512.74
 Brussels->Barcelona->Belgrade->Berlin->Brussels : 4,637.38
 Brussels->Barcelona->Berlin->Belgrade->Brussels : 5,565.86
 Brussels->Belgrade->Barcelona->Berlin->Brussels : 5,512.74
 Brussels->Belgrade->Berlin->Barcelona->Brussels : 5,565.86
 Brussels->Berlin->Barcelona->Belgrade->Brussels : 5,512.74
 Brussels->Berlin->Belgrade->Barcelona->Brussels : 4,637.38
```

Comment: I took another look at it now, and it works. The problem was that I made a few changes and adjustments in my files. Thanks!

Comment: AND haveing only three cities gives just the same distance any path you choose so I have to try with at least four cities.

Comment: Glad you determined what was wrong yourself. I've updated my answer to make it more memory efficient by eliminating the need to first read the csv data into a `dist_table` and then convert that into `dist_dict`, which it now creates directly from the file. I also added a fourth city to make the total distances vary.

Comment: I got it to work with four cities, and six cities, even though the solution for six cities took a lot of time. But I am also trying to implement a faster algorithm, like a simple hill climbing algorithm and a Genetic algorithm just to see the difference in efficience. But I don't know how to implement this in my program, do you have any easy solutions for this?

Comment: Yes, it should work for any number of cities. A more efficient algorithm would construct a tree structure (probably using dictionaries) where each node was the name of a city and a list of other cities sorted by distance. To find the shortest route would simply be a matter of traversing the tree and choosing the nearest city that had not yet been visited (which you could keep track of by keeping their names to an instance of the built-in [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) type). Even this may take a long time if there are a large number of cities.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it a little, you'll see that a combination of the form, `cityA-cityB + cityB-cityC + cityC-cityA` is actually just `A,B,C` slightly modified. Can you think of an algorithm to convert an `A,B,C` to `cityA-cityB + cityB-cityC + cityC-cityA` ? Perhaps you could combine that kind of modifying function with a python tool that generates unique combinations from your list.

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution:

```
from itertools import permutations
import csv

    sums = []

    for p in permutations(distance_table[0], 2):
      sums.append(sum(p))

    for s in sums:
        print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach using the permutations function is:

```
N = len(city_names)
for perm in permutations(range(N)):
  dist = sum(distance_table[perm[i]][perm[(i+1)%N]] for i in range(N))
  print perm,dist
```